# How to sum data of row has same id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My query :

```
"SELECT sent_who, sent_amount FROM game1 ORDER BY sent_who ASC;"
```

Output :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'sent_who' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'sent_amount' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'sent_who' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'sent_amount' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'sent_who' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'sent_amount' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'sent_who' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'sent_amount' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
```

What i want :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'sent_who' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'sent_amount' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'sent_who' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'sent_amount' => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
```

I want to merge same `sent_who` in array, also sum `sent_amount` in same array.
If i use GROUP BY instead of ORDER BY it works for sent_who, but it doesnt give sum of sent_amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sent_who, SUM(sent_amount) as total_sent_amount
FROM game1 
GROUP BY sent_who 
ORDER BY sent_who ASC
```

Using `SUM(sent_amount)` will sum all the values of sent_amount for the specific `sent_who` which we grouped using `GROUP BY sent_who`.

So you will get the array as you expect.